# How to filter multiple columns with condition using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

**Scenario**

I have the following excel sheet with values

[image]

**What I need**

I want to filter out values only when the following conditions met

`If Status = "RO" OR Status = "SS" OR (Status = "NO" AND StartDate <>"") OR Status = "INVEST")`

using excel filter with VBA.

This is a very big table and if it is possible through filtering techniques, it will be faster rather than doing comparison of values one by one and copy one by one. That is why I want to use filter. Is this possible?

A normal recording giving only the following which I can't figure out how to do in my situation

Eg: `ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$D$21").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="SS"`

But how to check with filter `if blank on start date and a particular value on Status`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your data up as an Excel table by selecting a cell in the populated range and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Add an additional column at the end called `Include`. 
In the top cell of that column put the following (it will autofilter down all rows):

```
=OR([Status] = "RO", [Status]  = "SS", AND([Status] = "NO",[Start Date] <>""),[Status] = "INVEST")
```

The use the following VBA lines in your code:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Yoursheetname").ListObjects("YourTableName").Range
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
    "TRUE"
End With
```

---

**Data:**

[image: data]